# How to convert a raw hexadecimal image to a html img

Tags: javascript, python, html, image

I have a raw hexadecimal representation of and image like this: `"FF00FF00FF00"`

Every 2 letters represent the color of one pixel, in this example it is 6 pixels white -black -white - black -white - black, 2x3 pixels (width x height).

I want to convert this into an html re-presentable image.

I was wondering what the best solution for this would be?

I was thinking of converting the HEX string one by one into base64 and then use a `<img>` tag to display it on an html page.

I was using python to convert it:

```
encoded = HEX_STRING.decode("hex").encode("base64")
```

Converting it pixel by pixel would give me this `/wAA/wAA/wAA`. Then I would add this as a `src` to an image tag: `<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo/wAA/wAA/wAA' alt='img'>`

This doesn't work.

The only other way I could think of is drawing an image pixel by pixel with html canvas.

I'm wondering if there is an easier solution?

Comment: interesting question, I'm not too much into the bytes/hex stuff, but what is the code that you actually are using, since I can't get what you have put into the question to make sense, what exactly is your hex_string, and have you used `codecs` anywhere?

Comment: I'm sending images from a client to a server and from there to another client. The images have to be converted into raw hexadecimal code (I do this pixel by pixel in JS on the frontend, then send the code. On the backend, the server, is python). The image is 300x150px, hex_string is 45000 pairs of Hexadecimal codes (FF,00,etc.). So intotal 90000 letters long.

Comment: i have not used codecs anywhere

Answer (score 2):

A basic way to do that:

```
import ast
import imageio
import numpy as np
data="FF00FF00FF00"*100
shape=(30,20)

to_int=ast.literal_eval(str("0x")+data)
to_array=np.frombuffer(to_int.to_bytes(len(data)//2,'big'),
np.uint8).reshape(shape)
##
imageio.imsave("try.png",to_array)
```

The image is there :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo/wAA/wAA/wAA` to make sense, `iVBORw0KGgo/wAA/wAA/wAA` would have to represent a valid base64-encoded PNG image.

The easy way to do this would be with canvas:

```js
function create_image(width, height, grayscale_pixels) {
    var $canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var image_data = context.createImageData(width, height);

    for (var i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        // Write (r, g, b, a)
        image_data[4 * i + 0] = grayscale_pixels[i];
        image_data[4 * i + 1] = grayscale_pixels[i];
        image_data[4 * i + 2] = grayscale_pixels[i];
        image_data[4 * i + 3] = 255;
    }

    context.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);

    return $canvas;
}
```

You can use `$canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` to get a usable `data:` URL.

If you're targeting browsers that don't support canvas and need a data URL, you'll have to do this the hard way. Instead of PNG, I would suggest you try the simpler BMP image format. Here's a Python example:

```
def pack_int8(n):
    return bytes([n & 0xFF])

def pack_int16(n):
    return pack_int8(n) + pack_int8(n >> 8)

def pack_int32(n):
    return pack_int16(n) + pack_int16(n >> 16)

def create_bmp(image):
    width = len(image[0])
    height = len(image)

    # Much faster to `b''.join(pixels)` than to `pixels += b'...'
    pixels = []

    for row in image:
        for r, g, b in row:
            pixels.append(pack_int8(r) + pack_int8(g) + pack_int8(b))

        # Pad the row
        pixels.append(b'\x00' * ((-3 * len(row)) % 4))

    size = 26 + sum(map(len, pixels))
    header = b''

    header += b'BM'
    header += pack_int32(26 + len(pixels))  # total size
    header += b'\x00\x00'                   # reserved1
    header += b'\x00\x00'                   # reserved2
    header += b'\x1a\x00\x00\x00'           # offset of pixels (2+4+2+2+4+4+2+2+2+2)

    header += b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00'           # header size (4+2+2+2+2)
    header += pack_int16(width)             # width
    header += pack_int16(height)            # height
    header += b'\x01\x00'                   # color planes
    header += b'\x18\x00'                   # bits per pixel (24)

    return header + b''.join(pixels)


with open('test.bmp', 'wb') as handle:
    width = 1000
    height = 1000

    image = [
        [((i+j-i**2+j**2-i*j) % 256,) * 3 for i in range(width)]
        for j in range(height)
    ]
    handle.write(create_bmp(image))
```

You can easily translate this to JavaScript and base64-encode it.